# Ubuntu 16.04 Lenovo fan noise

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, fan, fancontrol, noise

I am new to Linux systems.

Five days ago I installed Ubuntu. The first time there was no problem at all anywhere. But when I decided to go **Additional drivers** and chose nvidia driver, fan speed suddenly increased.

I tried restart, `acpi_osi` method but it didn't work.

I'm using a Lenovo z7080

Comment: Does your laptop have multiple graphic cards? I can't find out this from your laptop specification [here](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/z-series/z70-80/#tab-tech_specs). I think that _Up to NVIDIA GeForce 840M 2GB_ means your laptop has multiple graphic cards.

Comment: yes it has got nvidia gt840m 4 gb and also intel graphics

Comment: Maybe your laptop use NVIDIA graphic card as default. This card use more power and get hot so your laptop fan should be always on max speed to make it cold. Try to switch to your Intel graphic card.